# Does Linux run correctly with SpeedStep on Broadwell?

Tags: intel, stability

In this web article "[Working Around The Intel Core i7 5775C Broadwell Stability Issue On Linux](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=core-i7-5775c-oc-fixed-mode)", the author indicates that he and others have seen stability problems when running Linux on Broadwell-microarchitecture i7 processors.  I am having similar issues with a i7-5700HQ.  In both cases, a workaround related to [SpeedStep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) or similar power/performance throttling was discovered.

Is it possible that Intel has released a microarchitecture which does not run Linux (reliably) without disabling frequency scaling -- or is it more likely that these issues are due to manufacturing defects in the particular hardware units under test?

---

Update: The problems were fixed for me with the BIOS/[microcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode) update [desribed here](https://superuser.com/a/1003663/114579).  As noted there, problems were discovered while running Windows as well.  I don't have enough information about the update to know if this was Intel's fault or something specific to the manufacturer of my laptop.

Comment: The complexity of CPUs these days is mind-boggling.  Consequently, a design screwup is overwhelmingly more likely than a conspiracy, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @lcd047: A conspiracy isn't what I was thinking of -- but maybe just a lack of testing.  That Linux would fail to run reliably on the architecture seems highly improbably, but that is what I am seeing.  I really just want to know if my hardware is bad.  But I can't make it crash running only Windows, so this makes a hardware defect seem unlikely as well.

Comment: It probably boils down to lack of testing, yes.  On the other hand, if you have ever run coverage tests you probably know that getting 100% coverage is a pain in the rear even for a script with 1k lines.  For a CPU we're literally talking about billions of transistors.  Complete test coverage hasn't been possible even in theory since Intel 8080 in the mid 1970s.  For this reason, I personally never buy anything based on technology more recent than 1-2 years.  The difference in performance typically doesn't matter, but there are huge differences in price, and in bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am using kubuntu. but it has some trick to make it stable.

First, please update you BIOS to latest version. 
I were use old version BIOS, windows 7/10 is stable, but Linux is not. 
It must disable speedstep to make it more stable until updated it.

Second, Kubuntu must update to mainline kernel . 
otherwise, it will get error message like "Working Around The Intel Core i7 5775C Broadwell Stability Issue On Linux" said.

I am using 4.2.0-RC7-unstable , it works good.

you can try it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying about the kernel, but I did just find a BIOS update released the day *after* this answer was posted.  I'm currently testing with that -- initial indications are good.

Comment: I am pretty confident that the BIOS update solved the problem for me.